# STRAPI: Using auth0 for API Authentication in Strapi works and works not

Tags: auth0, strapi

Node: v12.16.1
Strapi: 3.0.0-beta.20.1

I'm new to strapi and have to say at first: I love it!

I want to use **Strapi** in addition with **Angular 9** and for authentication I want to use **Auth0**.

For my setup with Auth0 I followed the guide in the strapi documentation and customizied my permissons.js in the user-permissions plugin.
Well!

I have a very confusing issue.

When I get back my **access_token from Auth0** I put it to my calls as bearer authentication token, the request to the strapi endpoint works mostly for the first time, maybe sometimes the second and many more calls also, **and then it fails**. If I wait a few seconds then it works again, and after a successful call also it fails again. (also testing outside my angular-app with postman - same behavior)
If I work **with the strapi jwt, it works permanantly**, independet from my frequency of requests.

This is confusing me since a couple of days.

My response from strapi if it fails is
**Invalid token: Token did not match with Strapi and Auth0** as catched in the error part.

If it would never work I would have to say I'm doing something wrong, but it works sometimes, so I would say my way is technically correct. But of course I will do something wrong.

Has everybody else had an issue like that by authentication with Auth0 and strapi and understand what I try to explain?

Here is my snippet of code (I would say exactly copied from docu with a bit personalization):

```
...
try {
        const data = await axios({
          method: 'post',
          url: 'https://my.eu.auth0.com/userinfo',
          headers: {
            Authorization: ctx.request.header.authorization
          }
        });

        console.debug('data from Auth0: ' + JSON.stringify(data.data));
        // if you want do more validation test
        // feel free to add your code here.

        return await next();
      } catch (error) {
        return handleErrors(ctx, new Error('Invalid token: Token did not match with Strapi and Auth0'), 'unauthorized');
      }
...
```

I hope anybody had a similar issue and any idea how this can be fixed. Maybe it is an issue in Auth0.

Comment: The error is from Auth0, right?

Comment: Maybe. I can't figure it out. I have checked the logs in Auth0. There were no entries when it doesn't work.

Comment: If I call the Auth0 Resource directly with Postman, I get after a few (many) calls a response with "Too many requests". But this is ok, because then I habe send maybe 20 requests in just a few seconds to try it out. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to update url: 'https://my.eu.auth0.com/userinfo' replacing my.eu with your actual subdomain on auth0.